# @Html tags are not displayed in a div?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.actionlink

I'm working on asp.Net MVC4 project, and I need to create `ActionLink` for each element of a list.

Here is what I have done:

```
<div class="display-field" id="kalamsDiv"> 
    @foreach(Elections.Domain.Models.Kalam kalam in Model.Kalams)
    {
        Html.ActionLink(@kalam.Name, "Details", "Kalam", @kalam.KalamID, "");
        <br />
    }
</div>
```

And in the model of the view I have a list of "Kalam" object:

```
public virtual ICollection<Kalam> Kalams { get; set; }
```

But I'm not seeing any `ActionLink`, the div is empty, I can only see the line breaks : `<br />`.
What is the mistake I'm making?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@` before Html.ActionLink and remove them before `kalam` variable. Create an anonymous object for `routeValues` and pass null for `htmlAttributes`.

```
<div class="display-field" id="kalamsDiv"> 
    @foreach(Elections.Domain.Models.Kalam kalam in Model.Kalams)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(kalam.Name, "Details", "Kalam", new { ID = kalam.KalamID }, null);
        <br />
    }
</div>
```

Comment: It works now:D Can you please explain what @ do? I'm kinda new to MVC

Comment: @Hanady It tells Razor view engine you are beginning a C# code block. Yuo can take a look at this [post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) for quick reference